# Algebraic Manipulation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Given that 
$ a^2 - b^2 = 60 $

and

$a - b = 6 $
$a + b = 10$

Find value of $a\cdot b$

I tried

$(a-b)^2 = 6^2 \longrightarrow a^2 - 2ab + b^2 = 36$

Comment: You can solve explicitly for $a$ and $b$. If you find that boring, use $4ab=(a+b)^2-(a-b)^2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**. One may observe that
$$
2a=(a-b)+(a+b)=6+10=16
$$
$$
2b=(a+b)-(a-b)=10-6=4.
$$

Answer (score 1):

We can arrange the equations as a system of equations as follows
$$\begin{cases} a-b=6\\ a+b=10 \end{cases}$$

Now we can add the two equations

$$(a-b)+(a+b)=6+10$$
$$ 2a=16 \rightarrow a=8 $$
$$ a-b=6,\ 8-b=6\rightarrow b=2 $$

So the solutions are $a=8$ and $b=2$